# Does a file system "see" the storage device as a (very large) byte array?

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system, filesystems

I want to know how does a file system write to and read from a storage device.

I think this is how it works:

A file system doesn't access the storage device directly, but rather the storage device is presented (by the device driver of the storage device) to the file system as a (very large) byte array.

For example, if the file system wants to access a hard disk, it will simply access the byte array representing the hard disk.

This way a file system can work with any type of storage device (traditional hard disk, SSD, USB flash drive, etc.), and only the device driver for the storage device is changed.

This image shows what I have just explained:

[image]

Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: No. Underlying properties of the device are visible to filesystems - block sizes, geometry, etc. There are abstractions that represent these too but the abstraction is not 'giant array of bytes'.

Comment: The device driver will expose the drive as a block device. A block device is an abstraction whose main operations are to read/write blocks of data at specific positions. Whether you want to call that a "byte array" is up to you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww This question is about how to effectively build software stack to allow work with different storage devices - a basic programming. Though I understand your concern since the answer would imply just explanation of some underlying realities.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding will be closer to truth if you just change "byte array" to "block array".

Both the file system drivers and the device drivers "see" underlying devices as arrays of blocks. HDDs manufactured between 1980~2010 have classic physical block (=sector) size equal to 512 bytes. In 2010 AF (=Advanced Format) appeared and physical sector (=block) size increased to 4096 bytes, but only for some models.

Disc geometry addressing (CHS=cylinder-head-sector) was **declared as obsolete** in 2002 when LBA-48bit was introduced. Logical Block Addressing (LBA) is simple scheme to reach block (=sector) by specifying its sequential number from 0 to (2^48-1) in case of LBA48.

For example, before 2002 computers and storages were based on LBA-28bit, which gives maximum storage size:
(512 * 2^28) = (2^9 * 2^28) = 2^37 = 2^7 Gb = 128 Gb.

Maximum size of LBA48 storage having sector size of 512 bytes:
(512 * 2^48) = (2^9 * 2^28) = 2^57 = 2^17 Tb = 131072 Tb = 128 petabyte.

Maximum size of LBA48 storage having sector size of 4096 bytes:
(4096 * 2^48) = (2^12 * 2^48) = 2^60 = 2^20 Tb = 1048576 Tb = 1024 petabyte.

Comment: So for example if the HDD has a physical block (=sector) size equal to 512 bytes, then the file system will write to or read from the device driver for the HDD 512 bytes at a time?

Comment: Be careful answering questions like these. Some in the community feel answers should be downvoted, too. Also see [Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194963/173448)

Comment: @user247763 yes, precisely. Even if only a single byte needs a change, whole block will be rewritten.